# Shopify {{ product.price | money_without_trailing_zeros}}

Tags: javascript, shopify

I am new to Shopify.

I am trying to build a datalayer that can reference the product price on the addtocart event.
However, the liquid object product.price returns a string without decimals. for example 3499, where the price is 34.99

I am using the *{{ product.price | money_without_trailing_zeros}}*  but it returns an empty string.

I have also tried to use the  *{{ current_variant.price | money }}* taken from the product-template.liquid but it returns nothing too.

Here is my attempt:

```
<!-- jQuery -->
<script type="textjavascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<!-- Script -->
<script type="text/javascript">
  function fireEvent() {
    var price= {{ product.price | money_without_trailing_zeros}}
    console.log( price)
    // Wait a second for button to initiate.
    setTimeout(function() {      
      // Get div id.
  
  function sendEvent(){
  dataLayer.push({
  'event': 'addToCart',
  'ecommerce': {
    'currencyCode': 'EUR',
    'add': {                                // 'add' actionFieldObject measures.
      'products': [{                        //  adding a product to a shopping cart.
        'name': '{{ product.title }}',
        'id': '{{ product.id }}',
        'price': price ,
        'quantity': 1
       }]
    }
  }
});
  
  
  }  
  
document.getElementById("AddToCart").addEventListener("click", sendEvent)



}, 3000);
  }
  
  fireEvent();
</script>
```

Any help?

Comment: I think you need to add an attribute over the button with Id `AddToCart` and get the attribute using the JS attributes method, it is easy to handle rather than liquid in JS for a beginer.

Comment: Thanks for the swift reply. Would you happen to know how to do it in liquid? Or why my placeholder returns nothing?

Comment: to know about it you need to paste or send the snapshot of the whole page and where the code is placed, so I am able to check and tell you the exact reason for not working the code.

Comment: thanks again Onkar. but that is literally the whole code I am using.  i have updated also the post with the product template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

`var price= {{ product.price | money_without_trailing_zeros}}`

to

`var price= "{{ product.price | money_without_trailing_zeros}}"`

(note quotes around the liquid code)

---

or to

`var price= {{ product.price | money_without_trailing_zeros | json }}`

(note `| json` filter after the `| money_without_trailing_zeros` filter)

---

Your code likely outputs something like that - `var price = $34.99`, which would throw an error in JS because of the dollar sign (or any other currency sign/code whatever configured on your shop).

Comment: thanks for this Vladimir, the code is working now. it populates the  price with the following: <span class=money>$34.99</span>.  do you mind if i ask you if it s possible to access the product object from within a snippet?  The only way i found how to access the product object is using the following:  {{all_products['my-product'].vendor}}. I m trying to create a datalayer but it looks like not all the objects are accessible within a snippet and that i can access certain objects only in the their own theme, so for example the product object in the product theme. is this correct?

Comment: To remove <span> tag use `| strip_html` filter. Yes, you can access the product object as you're already using the price attribute of the one i.e. `product.price` so the `product` is the object in that case.

Comment: cheers man, forgive me if i repeat but is it fine to access all the possible objects from any snippet code (JS in my case) or can i access specific objects in the theme where they belong? for example i had trouble accessing the page.url object for some reason within another JS snippet.

Comment: You can only access objects in specific contexts. The `page` object can only be accessed from pages i.e. from paths like `/pages/{handle}`. The `product` object is accessible on product pages but can also be accessed while looping through collection products as well as through `cart.items` object or in search results etc. 
If you need to get the current URL consider using `request` object with `request.host` and `request.path` attributes, or just use JS `location` object.